# How can I map a vectorized function to a numpy array without using a for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ufunc

So here's what I already have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def monteCarloPi(n):
    np.random.seed()                 #seed the random number generator
    y = np.random.rand(n)*2 - 1      #n random samples on (-1,1)
    x = np.linspace(-1,1,n)          #x axis to plot against

    square = np.array([x,y])         #collecting axes as a single object

    mask1 = ((x**2 + y**2) < 1)      #filters

    hits = np.sum(mask1)             #calculating approximation
    ratio = hits/n
    pi_approx = ratio * 4

    return pi_approx
```

Here is what I would *like* to do:

```
x = np.arange(100,1000)
y = monteCarloPi(x)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

However, when I run the above code block, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-bf4dcedaa309> in <module>()
      1 x = np.arange(100,1000)
----> 2 y = monteCarloPi(x)
      3 plt.scatter(x,y)

    <ipython-input-51-8d5b36e22d4b> in monteCarloPi(n)
      1 def monteCarloPi(n):
      2     np.random.seed()                 #seed the random number generator
----> 3     y = np.random.rand(n)*2 - 1      #n random samples on (-1,1)
      4     x = np.linspace(-1,1,n)          #x axis to plot against
      5 

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.rand()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.random_sample()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.cont0_array()

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Based on my understanding of how broadcasting works in `numpy`, this *should* work. I could just use a `for` loop but that gets really slow really quickly as the number of samples goes up.

halp

Comment: `random.rand` only takes scalar values, numbers, the shape of the array it's supposed to generate.  You are passing it an array with many values, `x`.  The following line with `linspace` will also have problems with this `n`.  I don't see what `broadcasting` has to do with this.

Comment: okay... So what you're telling me is that the only way to run this simulation for many values of n is with a for loop?

Comment: I guess the reason I was thinking this was related to broadcasting is that the function outputs a scalar; what I want to happen is to put one array in and get a new one out.

Comment: The fast compiled numpy code works with rectangular arrays - each row has the same number of columns, and so on for higher dimensions.  Broadcasting lets us do math on arrays like this with various combinations of dimensions.  Vectorization, in the strict sense, means writing code that can operate with arrays with differing numbers of dimensions. It still loops, but it moves those loops down into compiled blocks of code.

Comment: Inside your function, different values of `n` produce different size arrays, `y`, `x`, `square`.  The `sum` compresses those back down to a scalar.  It can't work with several `n` at once because that would involve `y` etc arrays of different sizes.  `y` for n=100 can't be combined with `y` for n=200 into one 2d array.  Same for `x`, etc.  In `numpy` 'ragged arrays' are not fast.

Comment: by the way, your code doesn't use the `square` array.  Do you have clear idea as to why you create it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option, where the maximum sample size is based, then subsampling occurs if `start>0` (error handling not included).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def monteCarloPi(n,start=0,stride=1):
    np.random.seed()                 # seed the random number generator
    y = np.random.rand(n)*2 - 1      # n random samples on (-1,1)
    x = np.linspace(-1,1,n)          # x axis to plot against
    mask = ( x**2 + y**2 ) < 1       # masking
    samples = {}
    inds = arange(n)
    for k in range(n-start,n+1,stride):
        sub_inds = np.random.choice(inds,k,replace=False)
        sub_mask = mask[sub_inds]
        sub_hits = np.sum(sub_mask)
        ratio    = sub_hits/n
        pi_approx = ratio * 4
        samples[k]=pi_approx
    return pi_approx
```

This still requires a for loop, but it's handled inside the method quickly, since you're subsampling from one large random sample. To recreate your original call (running from `n=100` to `n=1000` [note that I am going up to `n=1000` here]):

```
estimates = monteCarloPi(1000,start=900)
plt.plot(estimates.keys(),estimates.values())
```

You could of course pass the original `x=arange(100,1001)`, but then there would need to be error checking in the method (to make sure an array or list was passed), and then `n` would be equal to the last element of `x` (`n=x[-1]`), and finally, the looping would be done over the elements of `x` (`for k in x:`).